# i got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory

Tags: java, android, usb, shared-libraries, smartcard

```
import javax.smartcardio.Card;
import javax.smartcardio.CardChannel;
import javax.smartcardio.CardException;
import javax.smartcardio.CardTerminal;
import javax.smartcardio.CommandAPDU;
import javax.smartcardio.ResponseAPDU;
import javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory; 
TerminalFactory terminalFactory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
```

i want to use usb Host communicating with smart card on android pad

but why do i get  **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory**

i already import......

and i don't know how to package this lib into app

Comment: Could you share us your runtime? You may be on an older 64 bit runtime. `smartcardio` is in the `javax` tree, which means it is an optional package. JRE's are not required to implement it.

Comment: i can run it on java project,but android project  can not run on my pad/phone

Answer (score 0):

When you did the development the required jar which contains

```
javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory
```

is in the classpath.

But when you did installation/deployment/packaging, did you ensure that the required jar is also packaged along with app.

Comment: thank for your reply your mean is add it in calsspath?

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094228/are-there-javax-smartcardio-analogues-on-android/15110077#15110077

Comment: thank you ,but i still don't know how to use and start it.  :'(